# redux saga watcher не работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

Я новичок в redux-saga, я решил создать сагу watcher для action type "SET_THEME", которая кладет данные в стор

Пробовал методы takeEvery, takeLatest

```
import { takeLatest, select, put } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* changeTheme() {
    const theme: string = yield select((state) => state.generalSettings.theme)

    yield put({type: "SET_THEME", payload: theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"})
}

export function* themeWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery("SET_THEME", changeTheme);
}
```

Так же есть инициализация rootSaga

```
import { all } from "redux-saga/effects";

import { themeWatcher } from "./generalSettings";

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        themeWatcher
    ])
}
```

SET_THEME PUT работает, но в state я не получаю данные, в чем может быть проблема? Так же при написании console.log("something") в функцию watcher или worker, я не получаю его в консоли

git repo: https://github.com/ignatiqq/anime-list/blob/master/src/redux/sagas/index.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в rootSaga. Watchers должны быть вызваны для начала работы.

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        themeWatcher()
    ])
}
```